# How to retrieve all PayPal transactions using TransactionSearch for a specified date range

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I've been doing a little research on PayPal's TransactionSearch method which is a part of their .NET SDK for C#...

The **TransactionSearch** method apparently returns only 100 results at a time for a given date range.

The issue is that I need to get all of the transactions for a given date range (usually a month time)...

I have searched throughout the internet but found no solutions whatsoever for this...

Is there a library or some nice implementation which could solve this issue ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a work around to the 100 transaction limit? I am facing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: @hellyale I have made a custom solution yes, it's quite neat and works very nicely =)

Comment: @hellyale the trick is to see what is the ACK response that PayPal returns with response. Given the fact if you try to retrieve transactions for 1 month time (for example), then you'll most likely find urself in the position that you can't retirieve more than 100 transactions at a time, which is why PayPal returns specific ACK response to let you know whether you've received all the transactions for the selected period. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 3):

No, the [PayPal Developer documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) clearly specifies:

> The maximum number of transactions that can be returned from a
>   TransactionSearch API call is 100.

This is not something that you can work around, it is a threshold used for throttling usage.

Your only possible solution would be to narrow your search criteria such that the number of records returned is less than 100, but that depends on the types of transactions with which you're working.

Comment: is there a way to retrieve transactions per day at least? Like as if a user has 100+ transactions per day, can they be retrieved by multiple calls?